# Dispatcher not raising unhandled exception event

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, dispatcher

I have the situation, that the Dispatcher does not raise the `UnhandledException`event, nor the `UnhandledExceptionFilter` event.

But according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.unhandledexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it should raise these events, when I get an exception in `Invoke`.

This is my minimal not working example:

```
[Test]
public void Should_raise_unhandled_exception_event()
{
    var control = new Canvas();
    var window = new Window { Content = control };
    window.Show();
    control.Dispatcher.UnhandledExceptionFilter += (s, e) =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("filter unhandled exception");
        Debug.WriteLine("e.RequestCatch: {0}", e.RequestCatch);
    };
    control.Dispatcher.UnhandledException += (s, e) =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("unhandled exception: {0}", e.Exception);
        e.Handled = true;
    };
    control.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(); });
    window.Close();
}
```

None of my eventhandlers gets called.
And I don't understand why. Could someone explain it?

Comment: What happens if you call `Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);` at the start of your test method?

Comment: This is from the `Forms`-namespace. I have a WPF-Application.

Comment: Why are you using `control.Dispatcher` and not `Application.Current.Dispatcher`?

Comment: Because I'm in a UnitTest. And in a real application they are the same instance. So it doesn't matter which one I use.

Comment: In tests the dispatcher is not going to be `Application.Current.Dispatcher` it will be `System.Windows.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher`. I have this in my ViewModel specially for that: `if (Application.Current != null)
            {
                _d = Application.Current.Dispatcher;
            }
            else
            {
                _d = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
            }` with :
`using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using System.Windows;`

Comment: That documentation is remarkably inaccurate.  No, when you use Invoke then the exception is marshaled back to the thread that called it.  Which will never cause the UnhandledException event to be raised, wrong thread.  When you use BeginInvoke then the exception is raised on the UI thread and you do get the event.  You can't emulate this behavior with a unit test, Application.Run() is required.

Comment: Just to put things straight the second type of the dispatcher is `System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` and NOT `System.Windows.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher`. BTW @HansPassant would that imply the use of `Invoke()` would have to be called on UI thread which makes no sense at all?

Comment: @HansPassant: during my investigations I noticed that exact behaviour you described. So I think, that there is no solution, just like you said. But it's a shame for the documention to say *Occurs when a thread exception is thrown and uncaught during execution of a delegate by way of* **Invoke** *or BeginInvoke.*

Comment: You can report documentation bugs at connect.microsoft.com.  Post the link to your feedback article and you'll get some SO users to vote for it.

Comment: @HansPassant: but I am wondering why that is. When you look at the source code of the Dispatcher, you can see, that an `Invoke` is just an `BeginInvoke` with a `Wait()` (in the `InvokeImpl`-Method). So I am wondering, why they behave differently. (Source: http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/wpf/src/Base/System/Windows/Threading/Dispatcher@cs/1407647/Dispatcher@cs)